# How to set multiple origins in the CORS json file with Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cors

I'm attempting to use multiple CORS origin sites with Google Storage.

Mozilla Firefox seems to not have any issues with multiple origins. But Google Chrome throws this error: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'FILE AT GOOGLE STORAGE' from origin 'https://example2.org' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://example1.org' that is not equal to the supplied origin.`

I have tried writing the cors json file like so:

```
[
    {
      "origin": ["https://example1.org", "https://example2.org"],
      "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
      "method": ["GET", "HEAD"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 1800
    } 
]
```

and like so:

```
[
    {
      "origin": ["https://example1.org"],
      "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
      "method": ["GET", "HEAD"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 1800
    },
    {
      "origin": ["https://example2.org"],
      "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
      "method": ["GET", "HEAD"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 1800
    }  
]
```

Google Chrome doesn't like either variants.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first way you specified it is correct, save a JSON file (ie. `bucket-cors-config.json`):

```
[{
  "origin": ["https://example1.org", "https://example2.org"],
  "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
  "method": ["GET", "HEAD"],
  "maxAgeSeconds": 1800
}]
```

Then use `gcloud` cli util to set on your bucket:

```sh
gsutil cors set bucket-cors-config.json gs://my-bucket
```

If you're checking your different origins in a browser and you're getting a CORS error, make sure it's not because of the browser cache. Some browsers will use the cached response on the wrong origin because the destination URLs match. This cached response will have the wrong origin header and cause the CORS error.

Comment: if you have a CDN/load balancer in front, clearing the CDN cache might help

Answer (score 1):

Arjun's method works well.

In case anyone is having issues with the preflight being cached, and doesn't wish to set the origin to a wildcard or reduce the cache window; old-school cache-busting exercises work well, such as a query-string value.

It's a bit of a hack, but it worked well in my use-case to append an origin query-string value:

```
const fetchHandler = url => fetch(`${url}?cache=${window.origin}`)
  .then(res => {
    if (res.ok) return Promise.resolve(res);
    return Promise.reject(res);
  })
  .catch(err => Promise.reject(err));

export default fetchHandler;
```